# Unable to formatt currency from string stemming from JSON

Tags: json, swift

I want to format a currency from a string:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .currency
formatter.numberStyle = .currency
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
thetotal_balancestring = "$456.78"
let number = formatter.number(from: thetotal_balancestring)
```

That works fine.
But if I am using a string that I got from JSON somehow I can't get it right although its clearly a string.

```
if (object["total_balance"] == nil) {
thetotal_balance = 0
} else {
thetotal_balancestring = (object["total_balance"] as! String)

let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .currency
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")

if let number = formatter.number(from: thetotal_balancestring) {
let amount = number.decimalValue
print(amount)
} else {
print ("could not succeed despite string seems valid:  \(thetotal_balancestring)")
}
```

**PRINTS: could not succeed despite string seems valid: 5,724.12**

Comment: If your string doesn't have a currency symbol then don't try to parse the string using a currency formatter. Just specify `.decimal` as the number style.

Comment: this works @rmaddy, Thanks! Your answers are the best as always.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure it is prefixed with `$`:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .currency
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
let thetotal_balancestring = "$5,724.12"
let number = formatter.number(from: thetotal_balancestring)
```

Result: `5724.12`

Comment: Why? Just parse the non-currency string using a `numberStyle` of `.decimal`.

Comment: @rmaddy , what if the initial string is as so though? 5724.6752 ? I do want it to round everything up nicely to 2 decimal places as in normal currency

Comment: The proper formatting will happen later when you format the number to a currency string when needed.